# mysql Duplicate entry error for primary key with similar values

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

This is how i created my table, i have composite key columns.

```
CREATE TABLE platformExchangePair(
pairName VARCHAR(15),
idExchangePlatform INT,
PRIMARY KEY (pairName,idExchangePlatform),
FOREIGN KEY (idExchangePlatform) REFERENCES exchangePlatform(idExchangePlatform)
);
```

now, im trying to insert this two values that are the same except for the last character 't':

value1 = testbtc:testusd

value2 = testbtc:testusd**t**

```
INSERT INTO platformExchangePair (pairName,idExchangePlatform) 
VALUES ('testbtc:testusd',1),('testbtc:testusdt',1);
```

output error:

```
1 Duplicate entry 'testbtc:testusd-1' for key 'platformExchangePair.PRIMARY' SQL.sql 75 1
```

it just makes no sense, they are not duplicated, is something missing on my table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the version of MySql you are using is 5.5.x, in which case when you try to insert a value for a `VARCHAR` column that is longer than its defined length, in your case longer than `15`, the value is truncated to the max length.

So, because the length of `'testbtc:testusdt'` is 16, it is truncated to `'testbtc:testusd'` (the first 15 chars) and the result is the dupicate.

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=76310c461c03001bb26d67ae017ee039).

The best you can do is increase the size of the column:

```
ALTER TABLE platformExchangePair MODIFY COLUMN pairName VARCHAR(20);
```